# Unable to login as sysdba

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ksh

I am unable to login as sysdba.  When I tried logging in,I got this error message:

```
$ sqlplus "/as sysdba"
ksh: sqlplus:  not found
```

Comment: From the 'sqlplus: not found' message, I would guess that it cannot find the sqlplus tool, and has nothing to do with the concrete user name. I guess you get the same with other user names as well. Check if sqlplus is properly installed/configured.

Answer (score 1):

You need add this environment to .profile for run sqlplus.

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/oracle/database
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=XXXX
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Either sqlplus was not installed (as Gaspar Nagy suggested), or the executable is not in the path.

You can add sqlplus, along with some other useful programs, to the path with a command like this:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/app/u01/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin
```

If you don't want to run that command every time, you can add it to your `~/.profile`, or create a set of common scripts to setup access to your database.  If you're missing the path, you might also be missing `ORACLE_SID` and other useful environment variables.